# How do I get color of a pixel (DOS Assembly 8086)

Tags: assembly, x86-16

How do I get the color of a speceific pixel in Assembly?
I need to compare the color of a pixel to red color.

```
proc GraphicsScreen
    mov al, 13h
    mov ah, 0
    int 10h
    ret
endp GraphicsScreen
```

Comment: What graphics mode are you in?

Comment: By reading from that pixel's location in video memory. It's not clear from your question exactly what the problem is, or which video mode you're operating in.

Comment: I updated the graphic mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind I found the answer:

```
mov ah,0Dh
mov cx,[X] 
mov dx,[Y]
int 10H ; AL = COLOR
cmp al, [COLOR]
```

Comment: Although the graphics mode that you use (13h) offers but 1 display page, you still should provide the required display page number in the `BH` register. `mov bh, 0`. Not every BIOS will ignore this parameter!

Comment: Hello @yoav! Could you explain to me what would be the [X] and [Y] in mov cx,[X], mov dx,[Y] ?

Comment: Its the position of the pixel you want to check its color on the Graphics Screen @YODA